# Android - Unable to instantiate activity: Didn't find class on path

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

On the Eclipse I'm using, I have no issues with building my app. On another machine, I am getting this error.

```
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510): Process: com.wdi.wdigateway, PID: 8510
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.wdi.wdigateway/com.wdi.wdiandroid.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.wdi.wdiandroid.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wdi.wdigateway-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.wdi.wdigateway-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.wdi.wdiandroid.LoginActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wdi.wdigateway-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.wdi.wdigateway-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2115)
08-24 15:31:57.426: E/AndroidRuntime(8510):     ... 11 more
```

I looked around for some answers, but they all involved declaring activities in the AndroidManifest, but I already declared all my Activities.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wdi.wdigateway"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.setup.SetupGatewayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setup_gateway" >

            <!-- android:parentActivityName="com.wdi.wdigateway.MainActivity" > -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.wdi.wdigateway.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.setup.SelectGateway"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_gateway" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.registration.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_registration" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.test.CommunicationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customize_gateway" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.setup.CustomizeGatewayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customize_gateway" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".FinishActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_finish" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.setup.EditDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_change_detail" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.notification.NotificationReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.notification.NotificationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_notification" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.wdi.wdiandroid.videoplayer.StreamActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Tried cleaning the project, re-opening it etc ?

Answer (score 0):

***Error states that you are using a class in your project that has not properly declared in the manifest !***

**Step-1)** Double check the declarations in the manifest !

**Step-2)** Clean and run the project

---

### ***`Try this Code`***

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SetupGatewayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setup_gateway"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >

        <!-- android:parentActivityName="com.wdi.wdigateway.MainActivity" > -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.wdi.wdigateway.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SelectGateway"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_select_gateway"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_registration"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CommunicationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customize_gateway"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CustomizeGatewayActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_customize_gateway"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FinishActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_finish"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EditDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_change_detail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".NotificationReceiver"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <activity
        android:name=".NotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_notification"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/login"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".StreamActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    </activity>
</application>
```